# creating two tables that share dependencies

Tags: sql-server

Im trying to create two tables in sql that share keys and im getting an error message saying:
Cannot create, drop, enable, or disable more than one constraint, column, index, or trigger named 'PK_vc_Status' in this context. Duplicate names are not allowed.

Im not very experienced with mysqlServer and am trying to figure out what's wrong with my code.

```
CREATE TABLE vc_VidCast (
    -- Columns for the VidCast table
    vc_VidCastID int identity,
    VidCastTitle varchar(50) not null,
    StartDateTime datetime,
    EndDateTime datetime, 
    ScheduleDurationMinutes int,
    RecordingURL varchar(50),
    vc_UserID int not null,
    vc_StatusID int not null,
    -- Constraints on the VidCast List table
    CONSTRAINT PK_vc_VidCast PRIMARY KEY (vc_VidCastID),
    CONSTRAINT FK1_vc_VidCast FOREIGN KEY (vc_UserID) REFERENCES vc_User(vc_UserID),
    CONSTRAINT FK2_vc_VidCast FOREIGN KEY (vc_StatusID) REFERENCES vc_Status(vc_StatusID)
)
-- End creating the VidCast table


-- Creating the Status table
CREATE TABLE vc_Status (
    -- Columns for the Status table
    vc_StatusID int Identity,
    StatusText varchar(20),
    -- Constraints on the Status Table
    CONSTRAINT PK_vc_Status PRIMARY Key (vc_StatusID),
    CONSTRAINT U1_vc_Status UNIQUE (StatusText),
    CONSTRAINT PK_vc_Status FOREIGN KEY (vc_StatusID) REFERENCES vc_VidCast(vc_StatusID)

)
-- End Creating The Status Table
```

Comment: I see 2 `PK_vc_Status` in your second table

Comment: You cannot create FK2_vc_VidCast until after you have created the other table and it's primary key first. Usually you add foreign keys as a second step AFTER you have created all your tables and their primary keys.

Comment: And you shouldn't be trying to use identity columns in both tables. Pick one table (that you will insert into first) to have the identity column. The second table will have just a typical integer column and you will set it by using the value of the identity column of the first table.